# How to make kubectl output a map with jsonpath output that is legal json?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to extract a "sub-map" from a K8s object using kubectl. The result has to be legal JSON syntax so it can be parsed by the Groovy JsonSlurper class.

If I run a command like this:

```
kubectl get configmap ... -o jsonpath="{.data}"
```

I get output like this:

```
map[...
```

This cannot be parsed by JsonSlurper.

If I instead do this:

```
kubectl get configmap ... -o json | jq .data
```

I get something like this:

```
{
    "...": "....",
```

This should be parseable by JsonSlurper.

You might first say, "well, why don't you just DO that then?".  I could, but I'm in a situation where I have to limit what applications I assume are installed in the environment.  I'm not certain that "jq" is available on all of our build nodes (they aren't running in a container yet).

Is there some way that I can make kubectl with jsonpath output emits a value in legal JSON syntax?

I'm currently using kubectl v1.14.0, with v1.13.5 on the server.

Comment: `-o json` outputs a valid json.  on the level of groovy evaluate json path you need after parsing.

Comment: Yeah, I already concluded that was the way to go. I was trying to avoid parsing the whole object, but it's not a big deal.